# Code 200 httpresponse on django

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, http-status-codes

I´m doing a service basic login, and I need to answer with code 200 and JSON in a Django view, but I don't know if is this the correct form using `HttpResponse` library?

```
def Login(email,password):      
    User=CUser()        
    if User.is_valid(email,password) :      
        user=User.find(email)
        datos['Id'] = str(user['Id'])
        datos['Name'] = user['Name']
        datos['LastName'] = user ['LastName']           
        datos['Email'] = user ['Email']
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json",status_code = 200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse( content_type = "application/json",status_code = 400)
```

I will use this response in android login, , and for that i need the status codes like django return on console

Answer (score 6):

Yup, [`HttpResponse.status_code`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code) can be set like this.

Note that you can improve your code by utilizing, introduced in Django 1.7, [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

> An HttpResponse subclass that helps to create a JSON-encoded response.
>   It inherits most behavior from its superclass with a couple
>   differences:
>
> Its default Content-Type header is set to application/json.